# How to remove duplicated rows from a MySQL? Delete

Tags: mysql, sql

Good afternoon, I'm new to the community, if I did something wrong at the time to ask this question please correct me, I would greatly appreciate it.
I have a table that contains two columns phone_number name them and Status.

```
Phone_number    status
“9999999999”    “A”
```

I need to delete duplicate between T1 and T2 if they have the same phone_number, but I want to make the number that has status '' A '';

I made an example trying to solve the problem, but something is missing because it gave me the result is not what I'm looking for.

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM
  tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
  ON t1.phone_number = t2.phone_number
     AND t1.status !="A"
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Only those 2 columns in the table?

Comment: Can you post some sample data for both tables t1,t2 and ur desired output

Comment: in tablename records, which are duplicated in phone_number, but with different status, interests me remove duplicates, but there are no unregister having the status '' A ''

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what  "delete between T1 and T2" means. You are obviously only trying to delete from T1 in your sample code.

The following deletes rows from t1 of the form (phone_number, not 'A') if there is a row in t2 of the form (same phone_number, 'A'). If T1 = T2 then this will delete all rows from T1 which are duplicates of the same phone number leaving only the copy of the phone number with status 'A'.

delete from t1 
   where t1.status != 'A' and 
         t1.phone_number in (select phone_number 
                                   from t2 
where t2.phone_number = t1.phone_number and t2.status = 'A');

Comment: in tablename records, which are duplicated in phone_number, but with different status, interests me remove duplicates, but there are no unregister having the status '' A ''

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you need is deleting from one table when the status is A on the other one; if so then you need two deletes:

```
DELETE t1
FROM
  tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
  ON t1.phone_number = t2.phone_number
  AND t1.status !='A' AND t2.status='A'

DELETE t2
FROM
  tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
  ON t1.phone_number = t2.phone_number
  AND t1.status ='A' AND t2.status !='A'
```

Comment: in tablename records, which are duplicated in phone_number, but with different status, interests me remove duplicates, but there are no unregister having the status '' A ''

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way may be to select only distinct rows from your t1 and inserting them into a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE `table`;
INSERT INTO `newtable` SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `table`;
```

Afterwards you can rename both tables appropriately. Of course, this makes sense only once.